# Controller mapping works but jsp giving 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a jersey webapp running and i'm trying to integrate spring mvc in to it. couple of breakpoints later i found that when controllers request mapping is accessible but the jsp is giving a 404. Any help here would be greatly helpful.

Here's my dispatcher view resolver

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

The jsp i'm trying to load is `login` and it is available at path `/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp`

My jersey servlet mapping is set to default mapper `/`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey-Web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have spring dispatcher set to dispatch on following patterns

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/f/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I access `/f/login` I see that the corresponding controller is being triggered. I'm returning a `ModelAndView` from my controller like this

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView( "login" );
return mav;
```

What I'm trying to achieve ?

I want all the jsp's and mentioned paths in url pattern to be served through mvcDispatcher and I want any other request to be served through jersey servlet

What I have tried ?

- I tried setting spring-mvc to map to default path `/`, it was rightly rejected saying that two default servlets are not allowed
- I tried making jersey servlet pattern to `/*` and spring-mvc to `/`, `*.jsp` but as the jsp spec mentioned the pattern `*.jsp` was overriden by the `/*`

**EDIT**

To reiterate my default servlet is **not** dispatcherServlet, my default servlet is jersey servlet

Comment: _I want all the jsp's ... to be served through spring mvc dispatcher_ - How is that supposed to work?

Comment: sorry, meant the mvcDispatcher servlet i'm using in the code above. edited the question

Comment: JSPs are delivered by the jsp servlet. The DispatcherServlet only forwards to a jsp, but does not deliver it. So mapping the DispatcherServlet to `*.jsp` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I tried removing all *.jsp tags but looks like it didn't make any difference. It still gives me a 404 for jsp even when the controller is called.

Answer (score 0):

As zeroflagL stated in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641964/controller-mapping-works-but-jsp-giving-404#comment40075308_25641964), JSP resources are (by default) served by the Servlet container's JSP `Servlet` which performs the compilation and rendering. The Servlet container maps this JSP `Servlet` to `*.jsp`. If you override that mapping with your `mvcDispatcher`, you are losing all that functionality and making the `DispatcherServlet` handles the corresponding requests. But your `DispatcherServlet` does not know how to handle these.

Get rid of those `*.jsp` mappings.

Comment: tried removing *.jsp mappings yet it didn't work. It still gives 404 though controller request mapping works

Comment: @zolo Did you remove all of them, even `<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</url-pattern>`? If you check your Spring logs, you'll see the `DispatcherServlet` complain if it's the one that handled the `forward` request.